# Is delayed initialization good or bad?

Tags: c#, initialization, lazy-initialization

I just found a class named HmeRevisionTracker that a colleague created.  It merely contains a List<> of simple objects.  CSimCharge, one of the most important classes in this project, contains an HmeRevisionTracker object as a public property declared like this:

```
    public HmeRevisionTracker RevisionTracker { get; private set; }
```

There is no reason why the object cannot be created in the CSimCharge constructor, since the HmeRevisionTracker is completely hard-coded, and nothing will ever change it.  But it isn't created there.  Instead, it's initialized to jull.  It's not created until it is used:

```
    void CheckForHeatModelRevision()
    {
        // Find the next revision that needs to be performed
        if (RevisionTracker == null && UseModel)
            RevisionTracker = new HmeRevisionTracker(ActualBase.CoilLoad, ActualBase.IsHeating);
```

As far as I know, there's no problem with this, but I'm curious.  Is there some disadvantage to this code that I'm not aware of?

Implementation shouldn't matter for this question, but here is some of it anyway:

```
public class HmeRevisionRule
{
    public double CheckPointThreshold { get; private set; }
    public bool RevisionNeeded { get; set; }
    public bool IsHeatingRule { get; private set; }
    public bool IsCoolingRule { get { return !IsHeatingRule; } }

    public HmeRevisionRule(double threshold, bool isHeatingRule)
    {
        CheckPointThreshold = threshold;
        RevisionNeeded = true;
        IsHeatingRule = isHeatingRule;
    }
}

public class HmeRevisionTracker
{
    public LinkedList<HmeRevisionRule> CheckPointRules { get; private set; }

    public HmeRevisionTracker(CSimCoilGroup coilLoad, bool isHeating)
    {
        CheckPointRules = new LinkedList<HmeRevisionRule>();

        // Default Heating & Cooling Check Points
        CheckPointRules.AddLast(new HmeRevisionRule(1.0 / 2.0, true));
        CheckPointRules.AddLast(new HmeRevisionRule(3.0 / 4.0, true));
        CheckPointRules.AddLast(new HmeRevisionRule(7.0 / 8.0, true));
        CheckPointRules.AddLast(new HmeRevisionRule(15.0 / 16.0, true));
        CheckPointRules.AddLast(new HmeRevisionRule(63.0 / 64.0, true));

        CheckPointRules.AddLast(new HmeRevisionRule(1.0 / 2.0, false));
        CheckPointRules.AddLast(new HmeRevisionRule(3.0 / 4.0, false));
        CheckPointRules.AddLast(new HmeRevisionRule(7.0 / 8.0, false));
        CheckPointRules.AddLast(new HmeRevisionRule(15.0 / 16.0, false));
        CheckPointRules.AddLast(new HmeRevisionRule(63.0 / 64.0, false));

        Initialize(coilLoad, isHeating);
    }
```

Initialization sets individual rules depending on the state of the charge.  Other methods of the class retrieve the required rule or change settings of a rule.

Answer (score 1):

This is called **Lazy Initialization**, and is a common practice to improve performance. Labeling it "good" or "bad" is subjective, and dependent on the context in which it's being used.

In your example, it's possible that the `HmeRevisionTracker` class may be expensive to initialize and therefore it should only be done when it's actually needed. There also may be some other implications when `RevisionTracker` is `null` that other code may rely on (i.e. it may indicate that other methods have not been called yet, describing some internal state).

There is an article on the topic of lazy initialization topic [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/lazy-initialization), which states, in part:

> Lazy initialization is primarily used to improve performance, avoid wasteful computation, and reduce program memory requirements. The most common scenarios are:
>
> - When you have an object that is expensive to create, and the program might not use it.
> - When you have an object that is expensive to create, and you want to defer its creation until after other expensive operations have been completed.

---

As mentioned in the article, there is a [`Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=netframework-4.8) class that was introduced in .NET 4.0 which could be used to make this more intentional and possibly reduce lines of code.

---

Finally, in regards to your statement:

> *There is no reason why the object cannot be created in the CSimCharge constructor*

Microsoft's [Member Design Guidelines on Constructor Design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/constructor) state:

> **✓ DO** minimal work in the constructor.
> Constructors should not do much work other than capture the constructor parameters. The cost of any other processing should be delayed until required.

(thanks @madreflection for this part!)

Answer (score 0):

It is my *personal opinion* that an object should be "ready to use" when the constructor finishes with it:  that the `List` object should therefore be built in the constructor.  The handful of nanoseconds required to do this, today, do not matter.  But the unexpected runtime errors and resulting (production?) application crashes could cost a lot of money.  Construct all the necessary things in the constructor, even if they are not used, and tear them down in the destructor.

If the attribute is `private` and might not actually be used, expressly initialize it to `null`.  The single most-important thing is that the value is not *unpredictable.*  ("It isn't zero, and yet it isn't any good.")

Comment: What *"unexpected runtime errors and resulting (production?) application crashes"* are you referring to?

Comment: How is the object not "ready to use" in the example question (the OP states that *"As far as I know, there's no problem with this"*)? Also, what is the basis for saying it only saves a "handful of nanoseconds" (we don't see the code behind `Initialize(coilLoad, isHeating);`, which may initialize some additional objects, make database calls, and/or run intensive file operations), and how can you say that *"nanoseconds...do not matter"* when we don't know what the program is doing? Not criticizing this answer, just asking for more clarification.

Comment: this is opinion based. Many developers argue that the ctor should be lightweight and don't do any heavy lifting. What if you have to create a million objects but don't need the expensive initialization? if your developers forget to call the init function then you will know it soon enough, this is an easy bug to fix. Creating an empty List is fine tho.

Comment: Regarding the "handful of nanoseconds":  initialization is relatively simple, and time required for it is trivial.  

And my thanks to all for taking the time to respond.